# rest url - having '/' as a path VALUE

Tags: jersey

I think this is not possible, but I need confirmation before throwing it away...

I have a GET REST endpoint with this pattern

```
/networks/{networkId}/publishers/{publisherId}/ratings
```

the problem I am facing is, publisherId could have '/' in its id, like the id could be "opt/foo/bar" (we have not control over this id, it is given to us by our clients).

So

/networks/68/publishers/opt/foo/bar/ratings - obviously does not work, getting a url not fond error.
/networks/68/publishers/opt%2ffoo%2fbar/ratings - also does not work.  same error.

I know passing it as a query param will work.  But I want to know if there is a way to make it work having it as a path param?

Thanks!

Comment: I know it's a cop-out, but replacing the "/" slash with something legal but unused like "_" underscore would avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL encoding is the right way to go but it looks like your container is decoding the slash before Jersey receives it.

Assuming you are using Tomcat, you can attempt to persuade Tomcat to allow the encoding, try:

```
tomcat/bin/setenv.bat
set 
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true"
```

I don't know if other containers have similar issues and settings.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this, but theoretically this should work in Jersey:

```
@Path("/networks/{networkId}/publishers/")
@GET
public String get(@PathParam("networkId") String networkId, @Context UriInfo ui) {
  java.util.List<PathSegment> segments = ui.getPathSegments();
  // Last segment is "ratings", the rest is your publisherId.
}
```

Comment: @Szpcske this is a good workaround...am sure this will work.  but my problem is i also have different sub-endpoints like /ratings, /summary etc, and I would like for them to be handled by different methods. If nothing works, I guess I can have this one entrypoint for all /publishers activities and then stem out to different methods from there.  Thanks!

Comment: Thinking of the path "/networks/{networkId}/publishers/" again, I am not sure any url that has a path segment after "/publishers", would match this one. So I doubt the method will be called in my case.  But I have to try it out. Am working on something important today, so this will have to wait until tomorrow.  Thanks!